# not to do this as well as that

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, negation, as

> They told me **not to investigate his financial activities as well as his brother's**.

Could that mean that they told me to investigate neither his nor his brother's financial activities?

Comment: It's inherently ambiguous. If there was any risk that the wrong interpretation might be applied, you could avoid this using ***...or** his brother's* / ***...while investigating** his brother's*.

Answer (score 1):

While the intended meaning is fairly clear

> They told me to investigate neither his financial activities nor his brother's

it is definitely not phrased well. Your explanatory gloss does as good a job as any. In fact, I am having a hard time seeing how this could be stated in a single sentence that is not awkward-sounding. This is about the best I can work out:

> They told me not to investigate either his financial activities or his brother's

It seems hard to me to make the negated verb with the compound object sound natural.

Comment: It might be easier to write in the passive: "They told me that both his and his brother's financial activities should not be investigated."